# preventing devise user session from being cached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching

I'm using action caching in a Rails app and I'm trying not to cache user sessions or flash messages.

Is there a good way to ignore these two components while caching an entire action in Rails other than using fragment caching?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. As soon as you have dynamic contents on a page like flash messages you have to cache with fragments.

[Fragment caching](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching)